# The app crashes when i set the recyclerview

Tags: android, parse-platform

when i put the recyclerview in the app, it crashed immediately when i run it.
I know am doing something wrong whether in myAdapter class or the way am calling it in the onCreate methode

Can anyone please point to me where am doing wrong in the code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        String t;
        String p;
        ParseFile i;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ads");
            query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // object will be your game score
                        t = parseObject.getString("title");
                        p = parseObject.getString("price");
                        i = parseObject.getParseFile("adPhoto");
                    } else {
                        // something went wrong
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public myAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public myAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_listing, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current = data.get(position);
        holder.t = current.title;
        holder.p = current.price;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

this is the code to call it in the mainActivity

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rec);
        adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

this is my getData methode

```
 public static List<Information> getData(){
        final List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
        query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                   Information current = new Information();
                    current.title = parseObject.getString("title");
                    current.price = parseObject.getString("price");
                    current.image = parseObject.getParseFile("adPhoto");
                    data.add(current);
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
```

This is the logcat

```
04-24 12:52:35.227    5414-5414/com.example.cashmoney.barakah E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cashmoney.barakah/com.example.cashmoney.barakah.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class RecyclerView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
```

this is the xml file that contains the recyclerview

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="8"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

please anyone guide me here, am lost

Comment: `RecyclerView` is not added in your project. @MazinAlmaskari

Comment: Which IDE you are using Android studio or Eclipse?

Comment: @Pooja - Android Studio

Comment: Have you added gradle dependency in your project `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+`? @MazinAlmaskari

Comment: If no list show, you need check your data list, if list is later available then your call to adapter, then you need call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after data ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RecyclerView` View with full package name in xml as:

```
           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: thanks. my app didn't crash after i put what u told me. but my adapter doesn't show in list.

Comment: @MazinAlmaskari: this is another issue please close this question accepting answer if help and ask a fresh question for new issue. Thanks

Comment: Please correct the close tag to `/>`, or </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

Answer (score 0):

For `RecyclerView layout,`Use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView                
    android:id="@+id/rec"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```